# Pandas: How to sum columns based on conditional of other column values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have the following pandas DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')

print(df)

     dog      A         B           C
0     dog1    0.787575  0.159330    0.053095
1     dog10   0.770698  0.169487    0.059815
2     dog11   0.792689  0.152043    0.055268
3     dog12   0.785066  0.160361    0.054573
4     dog13   0.795455  0.150464    0.054081
5     dog14   0.794873  0.150700    0.054426
..    ....
8     dog19   0.811585  0.140207    0.048208
9     dog2    0.797202  0.152033    0.050765
10    dog20   0.801607  0.145137    0.053256
11    dog21   0.792689  0.152043    0.055268
    ....
```

I create a new column by summing columns `"A"`, `"B"`, `"C"` as follows:

```
df['total_ABC'] = df[["A", "B", "B"]].sum(axis=1)
```

Now I would like to do this based on a conditional, i.e. if `"A" < 0.78` then create a new summed column `df['smallA_sum'] = df[["A", "B", "B"]].sum(axis=1)`. Otherwise, the value should be zero.

How does one create conditional statements like this?

My thought would be to use

```
df['smallA_sum'] = df1.apply(lambda row: (row['A']+row['B']+row['C']) if row['A'] < 0.78))
```

However, this doesn't work and I'm not able to specify axis.

How do you create a column based on the values of other columns?

You could also do something like for each `df['dog'] == 'dog2'`, create column `dog2_sum`, i.e.

```
 df['dog2_sum'] = df1.apply(lambda row: (row['A']+row['B']+row['C']) if df['dog'] == 'dog2'))
```

but my approach is incorrect.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The following should work, here we mask the df where the condition is met, this will set `NaN` to the rows where the condition isn't met so we call `fillna` on the new col:

```
In [67]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3), columns=list('ABC'))
df

Out[67]:
          A         B         C
0  0.197334  0.707852 -0.443475
1 -1.063765 -0.914877  1.585882
2  0.899477  1.064308  1.426789
3 -0.556486 -0.150080 -0.149494
4 -0.035858  0.777523 -0.453747

In [73]:    
df['total'] = df.loc[df['A'] > 0,['A','B']].sum(axis=1)
df['total'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
df

Out[73]:
          A         B         C     total
0  0.197334  0.707852 -0.443475  0.905186
1 -1.063765 -0.914877  1.585882  0.000000
2  0.899477  1.064308  1.426789  1.963785
3 -0.556486 -0.150080 -0.149494  0.000000
4 -0.035858  0.777523 -0.453747  0.000000
```

Another approach is to call [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html#pandas.DataFrame.where) on the `sum` result, this takes a value param to return when the condition isn't met:

```
In [75]:
df['total'] = df[['A','B']].sum(axis=1).where(df['A'] > 0, 0)
df

Out[75]:
          A         B         C     total
0  0.197334  0.707852 -0.443475  0.905186
1 -1.063765 -0.914877  1.585882  0.000000
2  0.899477  1.064308  1.426789  1.963785
3 -0.556486 -0.150080 -0.149494  0.000000
4 -0.035858  0.777523 -0.453747  0.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use `numpy.where()` method to select values. It returns elements chosen from the sum result if the condition is met, 0 otherwise. Due to a lower overhead, numpy methods are usually faster than their pandas cousins. Barring numba-jitted or Cython loops, this is the fastest approach for this specific task.

```py
import numpy as np
df['Total'] = np.where(df['A'] < 0.78, df[['A','B','C']].sum(axis=1), 0)
```

or

```py
df['total'] = np.where(df['dog'] == 'dog2', df[['A','B','C']].sum(axis=1), 0)
```