# How to sum values in pandas based on bool condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, boolean

I have the following dataframe:

```
                   High          Low  ...    Adj Close    bcc
Date                                  ...                    
2018-01-02  2695.889893  2682.360107  ...  2695.810059  False
2018-01-03  2714.370117  2697.770020  ...  2713.060059  False
2018-01-04  2729.290039  2719.070068  ...  2723.989990  False
2018-01-05  2743.449951  2727.919922  ...  2743.149902  False
2018-01-08  2748.510010  2737.600098  ...  2747.709961   True
                ...          ...  ...          ...    ...
2020-04-09  2818.570068  2762.360107  ...  2789.820068  False
2020-04-13  2782.459961  2721.169922  ...  2761.629883  False
2020-04-14  2851.850098  2805.100098  ...  2846.060059  False
2020-04-15  2801.879883  2761.540039  ...  2783.360107  False
2020-04-16  2806.510010  2764.320068  ...  2778.219971  False
```

How can i add the next 3 values of column `Low` whenever bcc column is `True` and save this data into a different dataframe?

Comment: You filter first, so `df.iloc[df['bcc'], 'Low'].sum()`

Comment: Looks like this already has an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37947641/pandas-how-to-sum-columns-based-on-conditional-of-other-column-values

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You mean `df.iloc[df['bcc'], 'Low'].sum(3) `?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I got `ValueError: Location based indexing can only have [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array] types`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `df.loc[df['bcc'], 'Low'].sum()`, not `iloc`. But I don't think that's what OP needs, since it doesn't handle `next 3 values`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of the efficiency of this code but you can try this :

```
match_idx = df.index[df.bcc == True].tolist()

next_three_rows_list = [list(range(idx+1,idx+4)) for idx in match_idx]
sums = []
for i in range(0,len(next_three_rows)):
    sums.append(df.loc[next_three_rows[i]].Low.sum())

new_df = pd.DataFrame(sums,columns=['sum'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. When i `next_three_rows_list = [list(range(idx+1,idx+4)) for idx in match_idx]` i get a ValueError `ValueError: Cannot add integral value to Timestamp without freq` How can i specify freq?

Comment: The `ValueError` is coming up because you have `Date` as your index. Try resetting the index using `df.index.rename('Date',inplace=True)` and `df =  df.reset_index()` before `match_idx = df.index[df.bcc == True].tolist()`. This will reset the index of your dataframe to integers.

Comment: I did exactly as you mentioned but i got  `Date         datetime64[ns]` when i did `df.dtypes`

Comment: It did not change the dtype after resetting. and got the same error

Comment: It worked after i restarted my the kernal! Thank for your help. Some parts of the code i need to meditate over