# How do I sum columns on the basis of a condition using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The df has the following columns,

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | Jan-19 | Feb-19 | Mar-19 | Apr-19 | May-19 | Jun-19 | Jul-19 | Aug-19 | Sep-19 | Oct-19 | Nov-19 | Dec-19  | Jan-20 | Feb-20 | Mar-20 | Apr-20 | May-20 | Jun-20 | Jul-20 | Aug-20 | Sep-20 | Oct-20 | Nov-20 | Dec-20

 ab  |  cd  |      | 10     |  12    | 14     | 15     | 16     | 12     | 13     |  7     | 82     | 76     | 100    | 98      | 10     |  12    | 14     | 15     | 16     | 12     | 13      |  7    | 82     | 76     | 100    | 98
```

The month columns have numbers. I want to **sum** the month columns on the following condition,

Condition,

1. If the `datetime.now().strftime('%b-%Y')` is anything from Jun-19(for example) to Oct-19, then I want to sum the month columns from Oct-19 to Feb-20. If it was anything from Jun-20 to Oct-20, then sum of columns from Oct-20 to Feb-21 and so on.
2. If the `datetime.now().strftime('%b-%Y')` is anything from Nov-19 to May-19, then I want to sum the month columns from Mar-20 to Sep-20. If it was anything from Nov-20 to May-20, then sum of columns Mar-21 to Sep-21 and so on.

There should be a **Total** column at the end.

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | Jan-19 | Feb-19 | Mar-19 | Apr-19 | May-19 | Jun-19 | Jul-19 | Aug-19 | Sep-19 | Oct-19 | Nov-19 | Dec-19  | Jan-20 | Feb-20 | Mar-20 | Apr-20 | May-20 | Jun-20 | Jul-20 | Aug-20 | Sep-20 | Oct-20 | Nov-20 | Dec-20 | Total

 ab  |  cd  |      | 10     |  12    | 14     | 15     | 16     | 12     | 13     |  7     | 82     | 76     | 100    | 98      | 10     |  12    | 14     | 15     | 16     | 12     | 13      |  7    | 82     | 76     | 100    | 98     | 296
```

Is there a way to create a **generic** condition for this so that it may work for x month and y year?

Comment: Just to clarify - you want to sum across the columns based on today's date?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: What do you want to happen if today's date isn't in 2019? I'm confused by the logic and how to interpret today's date. `datetime.now().strftime('%b-%y') == 'Feb-21'`

Comment: I have edited the question for more clarity. Is it still confusing?

Comment: Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37947641/pandas-how-to-sum-columns-based-on-conditional-of-other-column-values

Comment: If it is 'Feb-21' then the sum of months from 'Mar-21' to 'Sep-21'.

Comment: but why? how did you come up with that? is that (current month +1, current month + 7)?

Answer (score 0):

It is still confusing about what you are actually want to do.

But to your case, my suggestion is you can select the columns by their names and transpose the table.
Then you can sum the values along the row axis.

It is not very time costing on DataFrame.

In my opinion, the operation across the col axis in DataFrame is always harder than across the row axis.
Since in the row operation, one can use .query() function to easily filter the entries they want.
But not in the col direction.